# sum of new columns within a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have the below query:

```
SELECT distinct COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], sending_organisation AS [Supplier],
DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported) AS Month, DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported) AS Year,
Sum(Case When Status = 'Defect' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Defect,
Sum(Case When Status = 'Failed' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Failed,
Sum(Case When Status = 'Success' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Success,
 FROM [Tx]
 where Channel_Partner = 'CAT'
 and DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported) = '2018'
 and DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported) = 'March'
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported), sending_organisation
ORDER BY sending_organisation ASC
```

As you can see I have created the new columns of defect, success, failed.

I wanted to add another column within this same query in finding an aggregated sum of failed + success?

Any ideas how this could done without creating a table or doing more than one query?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a further column with another `COUNT(<expr>)`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] IN ('Success','Failed') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SuccessFailed
```

Further to the OP's comments, (on a totally unrelated matter), to return the data for the current month I would use:

```
AND Date_Reported >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0)
AND Date_Reportded < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()) + 1,0)
```

You should be able to alter this slighly for your own needs, if needed. Using something like `DATENAME` on your column isn't a good idea; it makes the query non-SARGable.

Comment: That's amazing thanks. Sorry one more question on the above query. As you can see currently I am writing the latest month/year manually. How can I adjust it so it automatically finds the latest date on the database?

Comment: @TarikulIslam do you mean that, if run today, it would return data for this/last month?

Comment: yes, rather than me entering may as month and 2018 as year (sorry i know above it says march)